# Removing the parts of surface which are outliers after running Screened Poisson Reconstruction in Meshlab

Tags: mesh, point-clouds, meshlab

after running the Screened Poisson Reconstruction in Meshlab, I got the mesh with some extended surface as in this figure
[image: l]

Does meshlab support any tools for removing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MeshLab is using an implementation of PoissonRecon, which is found here:
https://github.com/mkazhdan/PoissonRecon

What you are seeing is due to the default boundary condition used by the algorithm, which is a Neumann boundary condition. Unfortunately, MeshLab does not allow you to modify which boundary condition is being used for the Poisson solver. If you compile the actual source code, you can specify the Dirichlet boundary condition as a command line argument, which will prevent you from having this large open surface.

If you have issues with disconnected pieces, you can use the SurfaceTrimmer program from the same repo.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the filter - select Faces with edges longer than... and set the threshold you want.