# Meshlab creates weird bubbles when using poisson surface reconstruction

Tags: 3d, mesh, surface, poisson, meshlab

My task is to create a watertight surface out of a point-cloud (It's the model of a dam). For this I'm using MeshLab.

First thing I did was importing the .ply-file into Meshlab and normalize it.

This looked like this:

[image]

So far so good. For Remeshing and creating the surface I wanted to use Poisson Surface Reconstruction.

I tried different parameters but this is my best result:

[image]

As you can see it creates some weird bubbles in the lower right part of the model. And I can't figure out why this happens when the rest of my model gets modeled in the way I want it to be.
Any ideas what filters I could use or what parameters to change to get rid of this bubbles?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710155/7564109

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** After trying a lot of different filters with different tools, I came up with simplifying the point-cloud. After that, using the poisson surface reconstruction filter worked just fine without creating any weird bubbles.